# Updating selection of array's values

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays. Each array could have a different number of objects but they each have the same properties but could have different values. For example

```
var Array1 = [ { id: '1', value: a },
               { id: '2', value: b } ]

var Array2 = [ { id: '',  value: c },
               { id: '',  value: d },
               { id: '',  value: a } ]
```

What I want

```
AfterArray = [ { id: '1', value: a },
               { id: '3', value: c },
               { id: '4', value: d } ]
```

What's happening is that array1's object will be removed if it doesn't have array2's value. If it does have array2's value, it will keep the original id. If an object is in array2 that isn't in array1, an id will be generated (UUID).

I'm assuming it might go something like this

```
afterArray = []

this.Array1.forEach((res, i) => {
    this.Array2.forEach((res2, 2) => {
       if(res.value == res2.value){
           afterArray = afterArray.concat(this.Array1[i])
        }
        else {
        // do something if values are not present then add to array.
        // if added, add id to those empty properties. 
        }
    })
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: @userlkjsflkdsvm: If find the solutions correct, can you accept one? This way it feels good to the person who is answering.

Comment: Yes, I've been away from my computer. I'm looking at the answers now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a simple `map`ping over Array2 with a `find` inside it, to find the matching value in Array1 if it exists:

```js
const array1 = [
  {
    id: '1',
    value: 'a'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    value: 'b'
  }
];
const array2 = [
  {
    id: '',
    value: 'c'
  },
  {
    id: '',
    value: 'd'
  },
  {
    id: '',
    value: 'a'
  }
];



const generateId = (() => {
  // example generator function, use your own instead
  let possibleIds = ['3', '4'];
  let i = -1;
  return () => {
    i++;
    return possibleIds[i];
  };
})();

const result = array2.map(({ id, value }) => {
  // find a matching value in array1 to merge the id:
  const foundArr1Item = array1.find(({ value: ar1Val }) => ar1Val === value);
  // otherwise, generate a new ID:
  if (foundArr1Item) return { value, id: foundArr1Item.id };
  return { value, id: generateId() };
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Appreciate the help! Simple yet effective!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it right, this should do your job:
(find the comments in the code)

```js
Array1 = [

  {
    id: '1',
    value: "a"
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    value: "b"
  }
]

Array2 = [

  {
    id: '',
    value: "c"
  },
  {
    id: '',
    value: "d"
  },
  {
    id: '',
    value: "a"
  }
]

// keep Array1's objects if it has a value matching a value from any Array2 object 
// Also remove those objects from Array2
newArray1 = Array1.reduce((acc, elem) => {
  let indexOfObInArray2 = Array2.findIndex(eachArray2Elem => {
    return elem.value == eachArray2Elem.value
  });
  if (indexOfObInArray2 > -1) {
    acc.push(elem);
    Array2.splice(indexOfObInArray2, 1);
  }
  return acc;
}, [])

// Array of ids already taken by Objects from Array2, if they are non empty
idsTakenInArray2 = Array2.reduce((acc, x) => {
  if (x.id != "") {
    acc.push(x.id);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

// random number to give ids
randomId = 1;
Array2 = Array2.map(eachElem => {
  if (eachElem.id == '') {
    while (Array1.find(eachArray1Elem => {
        return eachArray1Elem.id == randomId
      }) || idsTakenInArray2.indexOf(randomId) !== -1) {
      randomId++;
    }
    eachElem.id = randomId;
    idsTakenInArray2.push(randomId);;
  }
  return eachElem;
})

console.log(newArray1.concat(Array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

check this, here is the code online https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zhzuqk , check your console you will see what you want to have as result

```
  formtarrays(array1,array2) {
    let ar = array1.concat(array2);
    // delete items that exist in array1 but not in array2
    ar = ar.filter((elem) => {
     return !(array1.findIndex(item => item.value === elem.value) !== -1 && array2.findIndex(item => item.value === elem.value) === -1)
    })
  // get distinct values
  const idList = [];
  const distinct = [];
  ar.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (item !== undefined) {
            idList['id'] = item.value;
            if (idList.indexOf(item.value) < 0) {
                if(item.id === '') {
                  item.id = (index + array1.length).toString();
                }
                distinct.push(item);
                idList.push(item.value);
            }
      } 
  })

  console.log(distinct);
  return distinct;
 }
```